# Passing extra scripts from view to header

Tags: php, codeigniter

So I'm basically trying to pass the `<link>` and `<script>` tags into my original header file from a modules view file (which is displayed in the body of the page). How can I pass variables that include these references?

Currently I have just put extra `<head></head>` tags into my module's view, but it just feels messy and dodgy to do so, as that means the head tags are used up the top of the page, and also mid-way down.

**Edit:** *Didn't realise that stack overflow edited out my tags that are crucial to this question! Sorry guys!*

Comment: by assigning them in your controller and send them to both views.

Comment: @Sneaksta, please post code examples. And also please clarify what exactly you are trying to accomplish.  Are you trying to have one view which contains the "head" tags? Are you trying to include something specific inside the head tags?

Comment: Views are buffered, if you load one inside another the same variable will be available to that second view too

Comment: Damien, does that mean though that I could pass a variable 'up'? For example, my views are like this: header, body -> module, footer. Could I pass a variable from the module to the header?

Comment: "Didn't realise that stack overflow edited out my tags" It doesn't edit out your tags, it just doesn't display HTML text.  You need to highlight code and select the `{}` in the toolbar.  There is a preview below the post, that should have shown you that the post wasn't formatted correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you are really in need of a Template setup for CodeIgniter. Here are links to some of my favorites:

http://williamsconcepts.com/ci/codeigniter/libraries/template/reference.html

http://philsturgeon.co.uk/demos/codeigniter-template/user_guide/

And my personal favorite for simplicity:

http://maestric.com/doc/php/codeigniter_template

EDIT:
Per @Sneaksta's question, here is how I add css scripts to my template:

In my master template I have this code:

```
<?php if (!empty($cssFiles)): ?>
<?php foreach ($cssFiles as $styleSheet): ?>
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="<?= base_url(); ?>styles/<?= $styleSheet; ?>" />
<?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Then in my controllers that might need to load different CSS files per function I do this:

```
$cssFiles = array('style1.css', 'style2.css', 'style3.css');
$this->template->set('cssFiles', $cssFiles);
```

Comment: regarding your personal favourite for the template, how would you add functionality so that it is possible to dynamically define the css scripts?

Comment: @Sneaksta, I have updated my answer to explain how I use dynamic stylesheets per controller/function.

Answer (score 0):

Sneaksta,

I think I understand what you are asking about, but I am not 100% sure because you don't have any code examples posted.

So I will give you an example of how you can have a "telescoping" View that allows you to modularly load different style tags inside the head tags.

As Damien Pirsy mentioned, Views are buffered, which means that CI makes a special output buffer and will concatenate a series of View objects together, and then output the final buffer content as a finished web page.

My example below is built on this sort of chain of thinking:

> End User 
>       (calls) --> Page Controller, which then:
>       (calls & passes params) --> Base View 
>       (calls multiple fragment views) --> Fragment View +
>                                       --> Fragment View +
>                                       --> Fragment View = Final Cumulative Page -->    (sent back as output ) --> End User

First make the "base View", which we will call "base.php" for reference sake:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
     <head>
          <!-- Base View -->
          <?php
                //This "if" + "isset()" statement is important,
                // because if you forget to pass the variable in the controller
                // CI will throw an error.
                // Also important: the name of variable ($style) MUST match the 
                // the name of the associative element in the controller! (See 
                // remarks below on handling this in the controller)
                if(isset($style))
                {
                        //Loading views is like a telescoping effect:
                        //A view may load other views into itself recursively
                        $this->load->view($style);
                }
                else
                {
                        //This echo statement will show a comment in
                        // source code if an error occurred during loading a view
                        echo "<!-- Style not found -->"); 
                }
          ?>

     </head>
     <body>
         <!-- Page Content Here -->
     </body>
</html>
```

Next you create the Style View (note: the following code fragment would be in a separate file all by itself) which we will call "style1.php", and must located with your other views in order for CI to find it, e.g. inside the "application/views" folder. This lets you swap out an inline style block declared in the header by just changing which style view is loaded:

```
<style type="text/css">
       /*Style 1:*/
       /*Just do something simple and obvious, i.e. turn text red*/
       body { color: red; }

</style>
```

Next you create the alternate Style View (note: the following code fragment would be in a separate file all by itself) which we will call "style2.php", and must located with your other views in order for CI to find it, e.g. inside the "application/views" folder. This lets you swap out an inline style block declared in the header by just changing which style view is loaded:

```
<style type="text/css">
       /*Style 2:*/
       /*Just do something simple and obvious, i.e. turn text blue*/
       body { color: blue; }

</style>
```

Now inside of our controller "example.php" we tell base.php to load the style1.php file into its header.  We do this by passing the file name as a parameter when we load the base.php view, by passing the file name as an element of an associative array, code igniter will parse that parameter array and create a variable with the same name as the associative element, and make that variable available to you inside the base.php view:

```
<?php

      class Example extends CI_Controller
      {
           //Constructor
           function __construct(){ parent::__construct(); }

           //Base View request handler
           function baseview()
           {
                  //Note: Make an array, be certain to name the element
                  //      the same as what will be expected inside base.php
                  $params = array("style" => "style1.php");

                  //Switching to load a different style is now easy
                  //  just comment out the line above, and uncomment the line below:
                  //$params = array("style" => "style2.php"); 

                  //Pass the parameters array into the CI load view method:
                  $this->load->view("base.php", $params); 
           }
      }

?>
```

The cumulative result should be the modular ability to switch the style tags inside the page header, by just specifying which "style view" to load (you could even build a model that retrieves which "style views" to load from a database table).  Obviously this approach has certain processing overhead constraints inside of a web browser, as you are constructing actual inline HTML source code, rather than linking to a CSS file through a link tag.  This means that the browser will not cache the css content for each page load, but will have to download it on each subsequent request.

Comment: Great answer! I didn't consider using the <style> tags as opposed to just linking in the css files. I'll give this a shot I think. I won't be doing a lot of this for loading in css, but I just wanted to make sure I was going about it a what that utilised better coding practise.

Comment: On reviewing your answer, perhaps it won't work, as I would need to access a style view from the module's assets/css folder and may need to be calling 2 different style views (depending how many modules are on a page)